# plotly scatter with second x axis by time(date) intervals

Tags: javascript, layout, plotly

for the example (scatter graph plotly.js):
[image]

code:

```
    var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
  mode: 'lines'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [2, 3, 4, 5],
  y: [16, 5, 11, 10],
  mode: 'lines'
};

var trace3 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [12, 9, 15, 12],
  mode: 'lines'
};

var data = [ trace1, trace2, trace3 ];

var layout = {
  title:'Line and Scatter Plot',
  height: 400,
  width: 480
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

codepen:
http://codepen.io/plotly/pen/LVMRMO

Any ideas on approach on how to highlight  with extra x-axis labels the example above in order to achieve something like (different background colour on the graph is not really required it be enough to be able to add the second x axis titles):
(UNLIKE THE EXAMPLE X AXIS WOULD BE DATES)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in the following docs, using shape drawings on canvas for example:

https://plot.ly/javascript/shapes/#highlighting-time-series-regions-with-rectangle-shapes

My code:

```
      //add highlighting intervals______________________________________
$scope.schedule=[
  {titel:'title1',start:'2012-01-01 00:01:00',end:'2012-01-31 23:59:00',color:'red'},
  {titel:'title2',start:'2012-02-01 00:01:00',end:'2012-02-29 23:59:00',color:'yellow'},
  {titel:'title3',start:'2012-03-01 00:01:00',end:'2012-03-31 23:59:00',color:'green'},
  {titel:'title4',start:'2012-04-01 00:01:00',end:'2012-04-30 23:59:00',color:'blue'},
  {titel:'title5',start:'2012-05-01 00:01:00',end:'2012-05-31 23:59:00',color:'orange'}
];
var shapes = [];
for(var i=0; i<$scope.schedule.length; i++){
  var shape ={};
  var shape ={
        type: 'rect',
        // x-reference is assigned to the x-values
        xref: 'x',
        // y-reference is assigned to the plot paper [0,1]
        yref: "paper",
        x0: $scope.schedule[i].start,
        y0: 0,
        x1: $scope.schedule[i].end,
        y1: 1,
        fillcolor: $scope.schedule[i].color,
        opacity: 0.2,
        line: {
            width: 0
        }
  };
  shapes.push(shape);
}
$scope.layout.shapes = shapes;
```

[image]